# htaccess show holding page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi I want to show a holding page to outside users but from my machine gain access to the site. Can I do this with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond !REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1
RewriteRule .* /holdingPage.html [R,L]
```

Replace `127.0.0.1` with your machine's IP.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but does this allow me to point all other users to a holding page?